# Submitting form inside Kendo Script Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, form-submit

I have this below code inside .cshtml file , where I am trying navigate to HttpPost **Index** Action method of **Account** Controller, on click of anchor tag (inside last table data section). But for some reason I am not able to navigate to HttpPost Index Action method, but the same code works fine when included outside script tag .

```
   <script id="ds-list-tpl" type="text/x-kendo-template">
                        <tr>                                
                            <td data-label="Online Store">#: Name #</td>
                            <td data-label="Phone">#: phone #</td>
                            <td data-label="Connect">
                                <span style="display:none;">#: Id #</span>
                                <form class="hl-form" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Index" id="introduce-me-form" method="post">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Account")" data-form-method="post" id="introduce-me-button" class="btn-primary">@Localizer["Connect"]</a>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </script>
    
    And below is the JS code I have written to submit the form 
    
    <script>
        $('a[data-form-method='post']').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#introduce-me-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            var element = $(this);
            var action = element.attr('href');
            element.closest('form').each(function () {
                var form = $(this);
                form.attr('action', action);
                form.submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
    
    I am new to Kendo , could somebody please help me on this .
    Thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your event binding to:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-form-method="post"]', function (event) {
```

Your table is probably being rendered **after** the event was bound. But as you are binding the event directly to `a` tags that **aren't** rendered yet, no event is bound. When you bind an event delegation to `document` for any `a`, that takes into account any `a` that already exists OR will be created in the document in future.